# Step function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use the `step` function in R. I want to use it with a binary variable as dependent variable. I use the following code:

```
library(leaps)
null=lm(SocEenz~1, data=dataScaled)
full=lm(SocEenz~., data=dataScaled)
```

Only I get the following errors when specifying `null` and `full`:

```
Warning messages:
1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") : using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored
2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
Final_Lot <- step(null, scope=list(lower=null, upper=full), direction="forward")
```

I think it does so since `SocEenz` is a factor. Because if I change that variable to a numeric it works.

Is there a way to use step with a factor as dependent variable?

Help is appreciated

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible sample of `dataScaled` (e.g. using `dput(dataScaled_smallSample)` ?

Answer (score 0):

`lm()` requires a numeric response. For a linear regression with a factor outcome you will need generalized linear models, which in R are done with the `glm()` function. For binomial and quasibinomial families the dependent variable can be a factor.
`step()` and `glm()` are compatible.